# Can JavaFX images be saved larger than it is?

Tags: canvas, printing, javafx, resize

I've decided to make an app that basically draws a certain image on a canvas for people based on inputted measurements. I'd then like for the person to be able to print out this image but in a much larger format (or save as a larger JPEG, PNG, PDF file).

So on the screen it will essentially be a matter of pixels but on print it will be inches long, if that all makes sense?

Would that be possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out how to scale the image to save it in a larger format, so this is for those who are still trying to work it out.

```
    // Create the canvas
    Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
    Group root = new Group();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(500, 600);              
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();       
    drawShapes(gc);
    root.getChildren().add(canvas);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();

    /* If you're going to scale your image by 2, 
    * for example, make sure your image size is large 
    * enough to contain the new image. As you can see, 
    * the image size is double the canvas size. */

    WritableImage wim = new WritableImage(1000, 1200);
    SnapshotParameters spa = new SnapshotParameters();

    // Scale the x and y axis by a factor of 2

    spa.setTransform(Transform.scale(2, 2));
    canvas.snapshot(spa, wim);

    File file = new File("CanvasImage.png");

    try {
        ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(wim, null), "png", file);
    } catch (Exception s) {
    }
```

Comment: You made my day (probably without knowing it :-)) because the same technique as described by you also works to get a crisp snapshot from a canvas on a Mac with a Retina display. The direct way to create a snapshot just results in a blury image in that case.